# How to handle different iPhone-storyboards with Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I created my project back before iOS8 and Xcode 6 came out. I'm supporting down to iOS 6.0, and have two Storyboards, one for iPhone and one for iPad.
Now, in Xcode 6, I'd like to add support for the new screen sizes (iPhone 6/6plus). When creating a new Storyboard, it is using the new format (square), which is good, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Can I decide which devices uses which storyboards? Or is the new Storyboard-setup supported on older iOS-versions?

**Can I throw away my old `Main_iPhone.storyboard` and create a new Xcode6-storyboard (with support for iPhone 6-sizes) while still supporting iOS 6/7? Or do I have to keep the old storyboards to work with versions below iOS8?**

If I need to keep them, where do I set the logic for which devices use which storyboards?

Comment: What are the chances you can drop iOS 6 support and proceed iOS 7+ ?

Comment: There is no need to add new story boards for the iPhones. You can just set the correct auto layout to make sure the iPhone screen adjust to the iPhone 6 and 6+ screen size. If you want to start using size classes just enable the size classes in you old iPhone storyboard and start using them. Also the correct names for you storyboard should be `Main~iphone.storyboard`. Now you can just load the storyboard `main` and iOS will pick the correct one, `~iphone` to `~ipad` or just the one without if there is not specific one.

Comment: @rckoenes When I'm starting my app on an iPhone 6 now, it it scaled up, giving less quality. You're saying that if I use AutoLayout on all my viewControllers in my *older* storyboard, it will actually use that layout to fit instead of scaling? If so, feel free to type it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, but you will need to add the correct size launch screen or a launch screen nib file to make to app detect that it can run without scale on the iPhone 6/6+

Comment: @rckoenes AH, that was the problem, yes. Once I added the Launch Screen, the app launched in full quality. The entire app looks ridiculous and misplaced now, so I have a lot of work in front of me with auto-layout. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

we can use more then one story board in one project.and call particular story board and identify the particular viewcontroller according to the identifier.

UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

```
PlaceDetailViewController *place=[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"placedetail"];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:place animated:YES];
```

}